# How to repeat unknown dimension in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

For example (I can do this with Theano without a problem):

`std_var = T.repeat(T.exp(log_var)[None, :], Mean.shape[0], axis=0)`

wrt TF Mean has shape (?, num), but log_var has shape (num,)

I don't know how to do the same in TensorFlow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shape` to extract the shape of a placeholder during evaluation. Then simply `tile` the tensor. For instance, for:

```
num = 3
p1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, num))
p2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (num,))
```

the operation:

```
op = tf.tile(tf.reshape(p2, [1, -1]), (tf.shape(p1)[0], 1))
sess.run(op, feed_dict={p1:[[1,2,3],
                            [4,5,6]], 
                        p2: [1,2,1]})
```

will give:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.]], dtype=float32)
```

However, in most cases you actually do not need to do that since you can rely on the broadcasting behavior of TF operations. For instance:

```
op = tf.add(p1, p2)
sess.run(op, feed_dict={p1:[[1,2,3],
                            [4,5,6]], 
                        p2: [1,2,1]})
```

gives:

```
array([[ 2.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  7.,  7.]], dtype=float32)
```